# Is killing the dragon and losing a T1 tower a good exchange?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should you give up top tower for Dragon?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58351/when-should-you-give-up-top-tower-for-dragon)

Is it worth it? dragon gives more gold but you lose towervision.

Dragon Gives 40 more gold to everybody on youre team and 25 for the one who killed the dragon.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is a fair exchange to lose one of the side turrets, but not the mid turret. The mid lane is much smaller and is therefore more valuable to defend. The side turrets, however, are sometimes a hindrance later in the game as your laners try to guard a tower and are scared to move to other lanes because they want to defend the turret. Considering this, taking Dragon can only be done every 6 minutes and does indeed offer more gold for your team, and you can get a good sum of XP for those around the Dragon when it dies early game.

Answer (score 0):

Its very situational, but when you take Dragon you can often move the group into mid or bot and get a kill or take down that turret which definitely makes it worth it.

Additionally, if you kill dragon then you can get the exact Dragon timer and hopefully snowball it into a series of Dragons for your team.

On the other hand, if you take Dragon and the enemy is able to transition into Baron or take a second turret then it is definitely not worth it. Just use your best judgement and realize what you are gaining and losing.

Answer (score 0):

A side turret is perfectly fine to exchange for a dragon.

Mid towers are too important as they allow for two zones of your jungle to be safer than if they weren't there, rather than just the top half or bottom half zones of the jungle.

Answer (score 0):

Taking dragon in exchange for a sidelane turret is definitely worth it, if top turret gets pushed down while u go get dragon, u can freeze lane at your inner turret afterwards, and be safe knowing that the dragon objective is down and the only thing the other top can do is either risk getting ganked while over extended, or try to gank your team, which won't work if you have the proper wards.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at it from just a gold stand point dragon is worth more.

Dragon = 190g x 5 = 950g
 -1 player also gets a little extra gold for last hitting dragon.

1 Turret = 150g x 5 = 750g

Another aspect of this trade is map control. If your team is already suffering from bad map control (and somehow you manage to take dragon) it may not be worth the extra 200g.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the dragon is a better option. Purely speaking of dragon vs tower.

- The dragon gives more gold.
- What you lose from the tower will be won back once you killed the enemy tower.
- The enemy team wont be killing the dragon over the next 6 minutes, you will not have to defend that dragon.
- You don't need to defend that tower either.

But, of course it's strongly situational. If you can save both, just save the tower first and then do dragon.
If the enemy or minions are killing bot or mid tower, it's easy to defend it. You probably already have 3 people at the dragon, and now you simply gank bot or mid before you go back to dragon. Or dispatch 1 and do the dragon with just 2 people.

If we're speaking of the first 3 towers, those will fall eventually anyway, and are not worth that much post laning phase. If we're talking inhibitor towers or base tower, you MUST defend those before doing dragon.

At the very least, make sure you keep the dragon warded and keep the enemy team away from it. If i had to choose between killing a enemy tower, or preventing my enemy from killing the dragon, i would certainly save the dragon.

Addition: I like to emphasize that getting dragon and keeping tower is of course the best option. The responsibility for killing the dragon lies at the bot laners early game. They should push or win there lane, and then kill dragon. If any jungler is around, the route around level 6 or 7 should be either gank bot->dragon or just call bot->dragon. If it's not possible to do the dragon at this point because of enemy aggression (and map control) either the jungler or the support should keep the dragon warded and prevent the enemy team from taking it instead.